# Linear operators and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Given the following matrix representation of an linear operator $T$ over the basis $B$:

$$[T]_B=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 1 \\
        2 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

How can we find the operator $T(x,y)$?

I don't know why my strategy doesn't work:

$T(x,y)=xT(1,0)+yT(0,1)=x(-1,2)+y(1,1)=(-x+y,2x+y)$.

I would like to know what's the *standard* method to find this operator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $(x,y)$ mean $xe_1 + ye_2$ (standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$) or are the row vectors also written with respect to $B$?

Comment: @ah11950 $(x,y)$ are the row vectors written with respect to $B$.

Comment: Then you are correct.

Comment: @ah11950 Sorry, I think $(x,y)$ is just the vector.

Comment: In which case, see Sami's answer below. (Or just play around with linear combinations to find out what $T(1,0), T(0,1)$ are (those are row vectors in the standard basis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix means that:
$$T(1,0)=-1(1,0)+2(1,1)=(1,2)\quad\text{and}\quad T(1,1)=1(1,0)+1(1,1)=(2,1).$$

In this particularly easy case, we conclude that:
$$T(0,1)=T((1,1)-(1,0))=T(1,1)-T(1,0)=(2,1)-(1,2)=(1,-1).$$

Now, for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$T(x,y)=T(x(1,0)+y(0,1))=xT(1,0)+yT(0,1)=x(1,2)+y(1,-1)=(x+y,2x-y)$$

Don't confuse vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and their coordinates in a basis.

**Edit.** To specifically answer your question in the comment:

> So what is this matrix $[T]_B(1,0)=(−1,2)$?

Let me first reword it properly, since your product isn't exactly valid:

> So what is this matrix $[T]_B\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}−1\\2\end{pmatrix}$?

The column $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ can be understood as the coordinates in the basis $B$ of the vector of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $u=(1,0)$ (the first vector of the basis $B$). Then:
$$[T(u)]_B=[T]_B[u]_B=[T]_B\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}−1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$
is understood as _the coordinates of the vector $T(u)$ in the basis $B$ are $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$, i.e.,
$$T(u)=-1(1,0)+2(1,1)=(1,2),$$
which should make sense.

If you asked:

> So what is this matrix $[T]_B\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$?

I'd answer: The column $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ can be understood as the coordinates in the basis $B$ of the vector of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $v=(1,1)$ (the second vector of the basis $B$). Then:
$$[T(v)]_B=[T]_B[v]_B=[T]_B\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
is understood as *the coordinates of the vector $T(v)$ in the basis $B$ are $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$*, i.e.,
$$T(v)=1(1,0)+1(1,1)=(2,1)$$
which should make sense too.

Comment: So what is this matrix $[T]_B(1,0)=(-1,2)$?

Comment: @user42912: Post edited to answer your question.

Comment: you said: "The column $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ can be understood as the coordinates in the basis $B$ of the vector of $\mathbb{R}^2$: $v=(1,1)$ (the second vector of the basis $B$)." why?

Comment: when we multiply the matrix $[T]_B$ by the column $(0,1)$, I thought we have $[0,1]_B$

Comment: @user42912 That's the definition of the coordinates of a vector in a basis: Let $\mathscr{B}=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ be a basis of a vector space $E$. Let $u\in E$. We know that $u$ can be uniquely written as a linear combination of the vectors of $\mathscr{B}$, say$$u=\lambda_1u_1+\cdots+\lambda_nu_n.$$ Then, by definition, the _coordinates of $u$ in $\mathscr{B}$ are:$$[u]_{\mathscr{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\\vdots\\\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @user42912 You might be confusing: 1) vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$: these are $n$-tuples of real numbers, written between parentheses, separated with comas; 2) column vectors that can be matrices or represent the coordinates of a vector in a basis.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much for the patience :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $B$ isn't the standard basis then your strategy isn't correct. The standard way to find $T(x,y)$ is: let $P$ the change matrix from the canonical basis to the basis $B$ then
$$T(x,y)= P[T]_BP^{-1}(x,y)^T=(x+y,2x-y)$$

Comment: Which step I was wrong? it seems correct.

Comment: The wrong step is to write $T(0,1)=(1,1)$ and you should write
$$T(1,1)=(1,1)$$ since you work in the basis $B$.